# MySQL Ñ latin character when row number is apply

Tags: mysql, numbers, row, iso-8859-1

I have a database with CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci, and this table in MySQL called `category`

```
category    name      time
niños       kid1     0:13:00
niños       kid2     0:24:00
niños       kid3     0:17:00
niños       kid4     0:23:00
```

When try to apply the row_number concept it doesn't count. Seems like doesn't detect the "category" field or doesn't understand the "niños" word with means `kids`.

My query is:

```
SELECT
  @catPos := IF (@cat = x.`category`, @catPos + 1, 1) AS 'position',
  @cat := x.`category`,
  x.* FROM ( 
     SELECT category, name, time FROM category
     ORDER BY category, time ASC
  )x, (SELECT @catPos:=1)a, (SELECT @cat:='')b;
```

Under this example the given result is:

```
position category    name      time
   1       niños     kid1     0:13:00
   1       niños     kid3     0:17:00
   1       niños     kid4     0:23:00
   1       niños     kid2     0:24:00
```

THE expected result should be

```
position category    name      time
   1       niños     kid1     0:13:00
   2       niños     kid3     0:17:00
   3       niños     kid4     0:23:00
   4       niños     kid2     0:24:00
```

It is anything wrong with the charset in the table that don't detect the ñ character?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is the character set (although it *could* be another problem).  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select` clause.  Hence, the variable assignments could be in any order.

I would recommend:

```
 SELECT c.*,
        (@rn := if(@c = c.category, @rn + 1,
                   if(@c := c.category, 1, 1)
                  )
        ) as position
 FROM category c CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @c := '' COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci, @rn := 0) params
 ORDER BY category, time ASC;
```

Comment: It looks like it not working... The funny thing id that with others category name like "senior" it words if you see the image...

Comment: Definitely it's something with the Ñ character. If I change the Ñ character for a N character (for example) it order perfectly fine. So as your as my SQL are just fine. Once more is a issue with the Ñ character. I means, this is normal?